# Extract Multiple XML Attributes to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have the below XML file that I want to extract specific XML attributes from then put those attributes into an excel file.

Below is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RECIPE xmlns="x-schema:recipe_schema.xml" Format="1.0" Name="Table1>
<STEP ChLocation="CH1"/>
<ENDPOINT/><ENDP_DEVICE Type=""/>
<PARAMS_STEP>
<REGULAR>
<PARAM Alias="Offset1" Name="Offset_1" Value="0"/>
<PARAM Alias="Offset2" Name="Offset_2" Value="-3.59"/>
<PARAM Alias="Offset3" Name="Offset_3" Value="0" />
<PARAM Alias="Offset4" Name="Offset_4" Value="5.56"/>
<PARAM Alias="Offset5" Name="Offset_5" Value="0"/>
<PARAM Alias="Offset6" Name="Offset_6" Value="-3.25"/>
<PARAM Alias="Offset7" Name="Offset_7" Value="4.66"/>
```

My code below finds all of the Node Attributes(0) and (2) - which is great. I am able to debug.print to the immediate window.

The issue arises when I try and export those to excel. I don't have an issue with extracting Attribute(0), because the string name is constant. However, I do not know how to extract Attribute(2), because the value will change on a regular basis so I cannot reference the value directly.

I was trying to research how to store Attribute(2) as a variable then call that variable, but all I could find was information on XSLT variable, and I was not sure of the VBA syntax to get that to work. I have been researching for a few days now, but cannot figure it out. Everything I see online deals with a literal Value.

I would like to export Attribute(0) and with the associated Attribute(2) to an excel table. 
Column 1 = Attribute(0) = Offsetx
   , and   Column 2 = Attribute(0) = Valuex

What is the best way to extract and export Attribute(2) to excel since I cannot directly call the value?

Thank you for any help in advance - I really appreciate it.

VBA Code below

```
Sub GetOffsetName_And_Values()

Dim GetOffsets As ThisWorkbook
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode


Dim strXML As String
Dim x As IXMLDOMNode

objXML.validateOnParse = False
strXML = "L:\Recipe\File.xml"

objXML.Load (strXML)

Set xmlNodeList = objXML.getElementsByTagName("*")
On Error Resume Next
For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList
    Debug.Print xmlNode.Attributes(0).Text
    Debug.Print xmlNode.Attributes(2).Text

Next xmlNode

If xmlNode.Attributes(0) = "Offset1" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2") = "Offset1"
If xmlNode.Attributes(0) = "Offset2" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3") = "Offset2"
If xmlNode.Attributes(0) = "Offset3" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4") = "Offset3"
If xmlNode.Attributes(0) = "Offset4" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5") = "Offset4"
If xmlNode.Attributes(0) = "Offset6" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A6") = "Offset6"
If xmlNode.Attributes(0) = "Offset7" Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A7") = "Offset7"


Set objXML = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: *because the value will change on a regular basis*...the value number itself or the name **Value** will change?

Comment: Unrelated to question but consider replacing all those `IF` statements with this single line:  `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Right(xmlNode.Attributes(0),1).Value = xmlNode.Attributes(0).Text`

Comment: The number changes. For example, right now Alias="Offset1" and Value="0", but the number changes every week. So next week it could be Alias="Offset1" and Value="2.5".

Comment: @Scott, yeah it definitely should be cleaned up. I will update it to use your syntax tonight. Thank you. I am new to VBA.

Comment: @mplh2008 in that case this line should work for the Value: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Right(xmlNode.Attributes(0).Text,1).Value = xmlNode.Attributes(2).Text` ... also see the edit I made to the 'Right` wrapper on the right side of this equation. I got it wrong in my first comment.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Scott. I will have to try this out tomorrow and post an update.

Comment: @Scott, I cannot get the code to work for me. It compiles just fine, but does not produce any output to excel.   [ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Right(xmlNode.Attributes(0).Text, 1)).Value = xmlNode.Attributes(2).Text]

Answer (score 0):

So I did some more researching and I was able to get all the attributes I needed to print to excel in two columns. The code still needs to be tweaked some, but overall this works.

```
Sub GetOffsetName_And_Values2()

Dim GetOffsets As ThisWorkbook
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Integer
Dim strXML As String

objXML.validateOnParse = False
strXML = "L:\Recipe\File.xml"

objXML.Load (strXML)


Set xmlNodeList = objXML.getElementsByTagName("*")
On Error Resume Next
For Each xmlNode In xmlNodeList

i = i + 1
       'Debug.Print xmlNode.Attributes(0).NodeValue
       'Debug.Print xmlNode.Attributes(2).NodeValue


       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(i)
            .Cells(1).Value = xmlNode.Attributes(0).NodeValue
            .Cells(2).Value = xmlNode.Attributes(2).NodeValue
       End With

Next xmlNode
Set objXML = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does anyone know a way to modify the above code to be able to past in multiple attributes from 4 different files?

Comment: I need to account for the objXML.Load of 4 different XML files at the same time. `code` `objXML.Load(strXML), objXML.Load(strXML2), objXML.Load(strXML3), objXML.Load(strXML4)` Right now the code complies, but it only puts the attributes from the last file into excel, it basically overwrites the other 3 files attributes as it loops through the code. I would like the attributes(0) and (2) from all 4 files to input in columns 1 through 8. I thought this would be an easy tweak to the code, but I've been having issues with it.